# Retornar un Texto de JSON en UTF8 o otra opción

Tags: flutter, dart

Hola recién empiezo a hacer una API con Flutter, pero me topé con un pequeño problemita que no consigo solucionar, no tengo mucha experiencia pero entre copiar y pegar códigos y lo básico que sé de programación puedo modificar y hacer que funcione a mi manera. Pero...

Quiero hacer una api que en la primera página me muestre un texto (un versículo bíblico), tengo varia opciones para ello, la mas fácil seria acrecentar este enlace que ya viene hecho pero el texto...tiene un formato que sale mal.

Biblegateway [JSON BIBLEGATEWAY](https://www.biblegateway.com/votd/get/?format=json&version=RVR1960)

El código me lo muestra exactamente como está (o sea sin acentos).

Otra opción seria utilizar otra api de otras páginas, en todo caso me topo con otra barrera para mi que no encuentro la salida. Con ejemplos de código si que me funcionan pero cuando quiero hacer algo para mi ya se me pasa algo por alto.

Hasta ese código me funciona bien, me llega dados en snapshot data lo cual quiero pasar a imprimir en la pantalla del móvil, ¿Qué tengo que hacer?

```
 body: FutureBuilder(
        future: getUsuarios(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          } else {
            return Text(snapshot.data); // hasta aqui todo bien me llega lo siguiente
//book:Book
  //abbrev:Abbrev
  //author:"Jeremias"
  //group:"Profetas maiores"
  //name:"Jeremias"
  //version:"rvr"
  //hashCode:145307032
  //runtimeType:Type (Book)
//chapter:31
//number:32
//text:"No como el pacto que hice con sus padres el día que tomé su mano para sacarlos de tierra de //Egipto; porque ellos invalidaron mi …"
//hashCode:925146177
//runtimeType:Type (ReqResRespuesta)
          }
```

Lo que Quiero es imprimir en pantalla *text* y *versión*.

Gracias

Comment: el tipo de dato de snapshot.data, te llega ahi en ese punto como dynamic, o como un tipo de alguna clase ya parseado.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te puedo recomendar es crear un modelo de datos de la respuesta que obtienes de la API, es decir, algo como esto:

```
import 'dart:convert';

Versiculo versiculoFromJson(String str) => Versiculo.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String versiculoToJson(Versiculo data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Versiculo {
    Versiculo({
        this.votd,
    });

    Votd votd;

    factory Versiculo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Versiculo(
        votd: Votd.fromJson(json["votd"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "votd": votd.toJson(),
    };
}

class Votd {
    Votd({
        this.text,
        this.content,
        this.displayRef,
        this.reference,
        this.permalink,
        this.copyright,
        this.copyrightlink,
        this.audiolink,
        this.day,
        this.month,
        this.year,
        this.version,
        this.versionId,
        this.merchandising,
    });

    String text;
    String content;
    String displayRef;
    String reference;
    String permalink;
    String copyright;
    String copyrightlink;
    String audiolink;
    String day;
    String month;
    String year;
    String version;
    String versionId;
    String merchandising;

    factory Votd.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Votd(
        text: json["text"],
        content: json["content"],
        displayRef: json["display_ref"],
        reference: json["reference"],
        permalink: json["permalink"],
        copyright: json["copyright"],
        copyrightlink: json["copyrightlink"],
        audiolink: json["audiolink"],
        day: json["day"],
        month: json["month"],
        year: json["year"],
        version: json["version"],
        versionId: json["version_id"],
        merchandising: json["merchandising"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "text": text,
        "content": content,
        "display_ref": displayRef,
        "reference": reference,
        "permalink": permalink,
        "copyright": copyright,
        "copyrightlink": copyrightlink,
        "audiolink": audiolink,
        "day": day,
        "month": month,
        "year": year,
        "version": version,
        "version_id": versionId,
        "merchandising": merchandising,
    };
}
```

La idea seria que crees un nuevo archivo con esa clase, luego en tu método de getusuarios() lo que haces es parsear la respuesta que obtienes de la API con esa clase que te acabo de colocar. Y asi podrias usar un builder como este:

```
builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Versiculo>> snapshot)
```

Ya después de eso podrías usar los nombres de la clase.

```
 if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          } else {
            return Text(snapshot.data) AQUI NECESITAS USAR UN LISTVIEW.BUILDER para que te vaya creando de manera consecutiva cada unos de los textos provenientes de la api.
```